# Execution failed for task processDebugResources

Tags: react-native

when you try to run the command:

```
react-native run-android
```

the following error occurs:

```
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: C:\Users\jefer\Desktop\react\new\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Package 'com.new' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as 'new' is a Java keyword.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
23 actionable tasks: 21 executed, 2 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug
```

I've tried using:

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

but it did not solve the problem ... I also deleted the android and iOS folders and used the commands:

```
react-native eject
react-native link
```

but it did not work.

Comment: what npm modules you're having in your project that require linking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your application package name

You set app package name is **com.new** in AndroifManifest.xml  is not a valid package name. Change application package name because **new** is **reserved keyword in java**